# Exact cover problem given the cost of the groups and the cost of the elements

Tags: python, algorithm

How to solve set cover if each group and each element has its own cost.

I came up with a greedy algorithm for this, but it does not work in all cases. Need an accurate algorithm.

That's all I could find on this topic:

[this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exact-cover-problem-algorithm-x-set-1/) and [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exact-cover-problem-algorithm-x-set-2-implementation-dlx/)

But there the algorithm does not work considering the cost of the groups, and the cost of each element separately.

Please tell me what I can use to solve this problem.

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

N = int(input())
dct = {}
groups = PriorityQueue()

for i in range(N):
    a,c = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
    dct[a] = c 

M = int(input())


for i in range(M): 
    k,c = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
    s = 0
    tmp = []
    for j in input().split():
        j_=int(j)
        if j_ in dct:
            s+=dct[j_]
            tmp.append(j_)
    d = c-s
    if d<0:
        groups.put([d, c, tmp])  

s = 0
while not groups.empty():
    #print(dct)
    #for i in groups.queue:
    #    print(i)
    g = groups.get()
    if g[0]>0:
        break
    #print('G',g)
    #print('-------')
    for i in g[2]:
        if i in dct:
            del(dct[i])
    s += g[1]
    groups_ = PriorityQueue()
    for i in range(len(groups.queue)):
            g_ = groups.get()
            s_ = 0
            tmp_ = []
            for i in g_[2]:
                if i in dct:
                    s_+=dct[i]
                    tmp_.append(i)
            d = g_[1]-s_
            groups_.put([d, g_[1], tmp_])
    groups = groups_ 

for i in dct:
    s+=dct[i]

print(s)
```

Comment: Show us the algorithm you have

Comment: added. Each time, the algorithm selects the most optimal group, when the groups end it goes through the remaining elements.